# Tools to manipulate doc file and convert them to pdf

Tags: pdf, doc

I am looking for some good tools (free or paid, though free tool is always preferred)
for doing following operations on word doc files:

1. Manipulation of doc/docx/text files (like replacing some placeholders with DB values) as well as
2. converts doc files to .pdf

Because, I will be using this tool in my WCF service library, 
So I am looking for a code library and not for a GUI based product.

Please share your experience regarding same.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspose has a decent collection of MS Office and PDF manipulation libraries.

[Aspose Homepage](http://www.aspose.com/)

On the off chance that you're only looking for PDFs for viewing or archival purposes, you could also setup a PDF print driver and print your office files into a given location using Automation. You could also edit Office files through Automation although this may be tedious.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. 
For my current scenerio, I will be using Aspose library to do doc/docx manipulation and then finally converting the result document to pdf after mail merge. I have downloaded the free 30-days trial version and it seems to solve all my issues. I would suggest anyone going to use Aspose to have the trial version first and then making the decision.

Answer (score 1):

[VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx) would give you access to the save as PDF from the Office applications.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer to [a related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356718/do-you-have-any-free-net-managed-code-for-converting-docx-to-pdf/1584076#1584076) where I recommend a number of ways to convert your Word document to a format that is more easy to manipulate programmatically (using XSL-FO).