# Run Word 2010 as service with port to convert doc & docx to PDF format?

Tags: pdf, service, ms-word

We can run OpenOffice as a service with an open port to invoke an convert doc / docx to pdf etc (using jod convertor lib). Can something similar be done with word 2010? Reason is that some of the document formatting is not comming correct in OpenOffice & PDF.

Answer (score 4):

Running MS Word as a service is discouraged - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Some people have reported success though by installing various versions of office onto a server and controlling it via Automation.  You will find more information here in these links.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333459/convert-a-docx-document-to-pdf-as-a-service

[Do you have any free .Net managed code for converting DocX to PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356718/do-you-have-any-free-net-managed-code-for-converting-docx-to-pdf)

Comment: However, note that there is an official supported way to do this mentioned in the above article: "Word Automation Services is a new service application in SharePoint Server 2010. Word Automation Services provides unattended, server-side conversion of documents into formats that are supported by the Microsoft Word client application."

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/what-s-new-in-word-automation-services-for-developers